# Append text of the input box on radio button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to append the value of the input box when a particular radio button is clicked.

Rows of radio buttons are dynamically generated. Each row will have 7 radio buttons.

When buttons are clicked, the row id and its value is put into a text area using an array. However, now when the last radio button (missing) is clicked, not only the row id and the value but the text of the input box which gets displayed needs to be appended.

So far we have **14001290~01~01~CD0|15489587~03~01~CM** where CDO and CM are the values of the radio buttons and the previous to it are the row ids.

What we need now is **14001290~01~01~CD0|15489587~03~01~CM~Append this text|87554585~02~04~CD1** ?

This is my code.

```
$("input:radio").hover(
function() {
$(this).prev('.r-title').show();
  }, function() {
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
  }
});
$("input:radio").click( 
function () {
$(this).parent().parent().find('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;
var clicked =[];
$("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
$(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').show(); 
$('table').find(":not(.pend) >input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
clicked.push(selectedId+"~"+this.value); 
}); //checked
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/jj4Uv/20/)

Hoping someone will help me. If you are not sure about the question please ask ? Thanks

Comment: The "Append this text" is editable... do you expect the summary output to change as you type (or when you lose focus on those edit boxes)?

Comment: When should the text be added ? If it's as you click on the lastcheckbox then you're assuming the user has entered someting into the input box already ? Otherwise, it would need to be on the onBlur (or onChange) event of the m-notes input box- maybe like this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KGrnm/12/

Comment: @TrueBlueAssie..I don't mind when either when they type or when then lose focus.

Comment: @user2808054..To be honest the input text value will be empty. The text can be added as they type or before clicking the next radio button or save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/jj4Uv/22/

Feel free to remove all the comments :) Basically it updates on keyup for the text boxes and radio check changes.

```
// Hover shows/hides the additional information
$("input:radio").hover(function () {
    $(this).prev('.r-title').show();
}, function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
    }
});

/* $this is the radio button */    
function updateSummary($this){
    $this.closest('[id]').find('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
    var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;

    // Array of clicked items
    var clicked = [];

    // Set number of selected items
    $("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);

    // Show the title and notes next to the radio button
    $this.siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').show();

    // Find all checked radio buttons
    $('table').find(":not(.pend) >input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        // Find closest ancestor with an id
        // See if we have a text box, if so use the text
        var $text = $(this).siblings('input[type=text]:visible');
        var selectedId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
        var value = selectedId + "~" + $(this).val();
        if ($text.length)
        {
            value += "~" + $text.val();
        }
        clicked.push(value);
    }); //checked

    // Display the selected ids 
    $("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
}

// Radio selection changes selected options
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    updateSummary($(this));    
});
$('input[type=text].m-notes').bind('keyup', function () {
    // Pass the target radio button to our helper
    updateSummary($(this).siblings(':radio'));
});
```

I noticed you were using an older version of JQuery otherwise I would have switched the events to use delegated version of `on` instead of `bind'.

Comment: It can be made slimmer, but wanted you to recognise your code :) basically always factor out the update part if you want multiple sources of change.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, we are using 1.6. I might have to call on you again..;o))

Comment: you need to add more checking if the val itself empty

Comment: @Amr Bedair: I will leave that to the asker, as they do not specify the rules for blank entries :) It is often easier on the receiving end if the delimiters are there for blank entries too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
$('table').find(":not(.pend) >input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
    var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var newVal = ($(this).next('.m-notes:visible').length) ? this.value + "~" + $(this).next('.m-notes:visible').val() : this.value;
    clicked.push(selectedId + "~" + newVal);
}); //checked
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
```

as per your latest comment you can add this:

```
$('.m-notes').keyup(function () {
   var $self = $(this);
   var clicked = [];
   $('table').find(":not(.pend) >input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
      var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
      var newVal =  this.value + "~" + $(this).next('.m-notes').val();
      clicked.push(selectedId + "~" + newVal);
   }); //checked
   $("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});
```

---

`var newVal` try declaring this var and do a ternary operation to check if the next `.m-notes` textbox is visible or not if visible the concatenate the `radio` value to the `textbox` value.

#### [You can take a look at this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/21/)

#### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/23/)

Comment: Hi! Jai, thank you and you are very close. The input box will be empty so "Append this text" will not be there. Can we add the text as they type on the input box.

Comment: Hi! Jai..Thank you so much. Much appreciated. Short and nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:radio").hover(function() {
    $(this).prev('.r-title').show();
}, function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
    }
});
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
    var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;
    var clicked =[];
    $("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
    $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').show(); 
    $('table').find(":not(.pend) >input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var text = $(this).siblings('input.m-notes:visible').val();
clicked.push(selectedId+"~"+this.value+text); 
 }); //checked
    $("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});
```

you need some if to check that is no an empty string and to add '~' before your string

Comment: Thank you, Amr. I had done the checking partly but I was messing up so decided to ask for help with what I had working.